# How to insert text using "sed -e"

Tags: bash, sed

For example, I have a file named `test_sed`, it's content is like this:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

I want to insert content, for example "hello world", when there are three consecutive lines like `abc\ndef\nghi`. So I use `sed -f test.sed test_sed`. The script `test.sed` is written as below:

```
:begin
/abc/,/ghi/ {
  /ghi/! {
    $! {
      N;
      b begin
    }
  }
  /abc.*ghi/a hello world
}
```

And it works. But when I write it like this in command line:

```
sed -e ":begin; /abc/,/ghi/ { /ghi/! { $! { N; b begin }; }; /abc.*ghi/a hello world };" test_sed
```

It doesn't work and I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Do you just want to insert text on the third line? If that's the case, you can do: `sed -n 'p;3a "hello world"' yourfile`

Comment: @NullDev I think OP wants to match three consecutive lines

Comment: Yes, @Sundeep is right

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You should use single quotes to prevent `bash` from expanding the exclamation mark (`!`):

```
sed -e ':begin; /abc/,/ghi/ { /ghi/! { $! { N; b begin }; }; /abc.*ghi/a hello world };' test_sed
       ^                                                                               ^
```

It seems like you need to force insert a linebreak to let `sed` stop inserting, this worked for me:

```
$ sed -e ':begin; /abc/,/ghi/ { /ghi/! { $! { N; b begin }; }; /abc.*ghi/a hello world
 };' test_sed
```

Comment: @Lianshuai I believe so.

Comment: @Lianshuai "Insert before" and "append after" require a newline as command terminator.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `perl`, then it is much easier using `slurp` mode:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's~abc\Rdef\Rghi\R~$&hello world\n~' file

abc
def
ghi
hello world
jkl
```

Alternatively you can use `awk`:

```
awk '$1=="abc"{s=$1; for (i=1; i<=2; i++) {
     getline; s = s RS $1 } if (s=="abc\ndef\nghi") $0 = s RS "hello world"} 1' file

abc
def
ghi
hello world
jkl
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is finicky.  In particular, you seem to be using a version that allows the `a` command to not be immediately followed by a newline, so although the following works in BSD, it may not on gnu-sed:

```
$ sed -e ':begin
/abc/,/ghi/ { /ghi/! { $! { N; b begin
}; }; /abc.*ghi/a\
hello world
};' input
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/abc/!b;n;/def/!b;n;/ghi/a\hello world' file
```

If the first line contains `abc`, the second line contains `def` and the third line contains `ghi` then append `hello world`.

A more robust solution:

```
sed ':a;N;s/\n/&/2;Ta;/abc.*\n.*def.*\n.*ghi/!P;//!D;a\hello world' file
```

This allows for failures to be retried.